# How to type half Hindi character with Hindi (Bolnagri) layout?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, special-characters

I'm using *Hindi (Bolnagri)* layout to type in Hindi. I'm typing in Hindi for first time.

My problem is, I want to type `स्वाद`. How do I type that half `स`?

---

#### EDIT 1:

How to type `औ` with this layout?

---

#### EDIT 2:

How to type `र्श` as in `आदर्श`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To get half स you have to type स and then virama (hasnt) ् so that it looks like स् then type व. In Bolnagri the ् is typed by <kbd>X</kbd>.

To get और type <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and then <kbd>R</kbd>. Where <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> is the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key on the right of <kbd>Space Bar</kbd>.

In general, where the picture below shows two columns of characters on the same key, the bottom row of the left column is entered by <kbd>THAT KEY</kbd> itself. The bottom row of the right column is typed by <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>THAT KEY</kbd>. While <kbd>Shift</kbd> types the upper row characters.

Thus, <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> results in ओ and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> results in औ.

To get र्श type <kbd>R</kbd> and then <kbd>X</kbd> and then <kbd>Z</kbd>.

Another example: आदर्श :  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>and then <kbd>D</kbd> and then <kbd>R</kbd> and then <kbd>X</kbd> and then <kbd>Z</kbd>.

The full Bolnagri kekboard layout is:

[image]

Also see [Sanskrit fonts and half letters](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167373/sanskrit-fonts-and-half-letters)

**For Ubuntu 16.04 and 17.04 you must install the right language support**

Go to System Settings...> Language Support > Install Languages and  install Hindi (or any other Indian language).

**For older and newer versions of Ubuntu you can skip the above**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you type that in Terminal?

Comment: This answer solves my question, but I write mostly with **vi**, I need help!

Comment: See my answer to the old question [about Devnagri script in terminal and **vim**](http://askubuntu.com/questions/182642/devnagari-script-in-terminal). Also see [Is there a good mono spaced font for Devanagari script in the terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/8437/is-there-a-good-mono-spaced-font-for-devanagari-script-in-the-terminal).

Comment: भाई साहब, मौज कर दी। 

Answer (score 4):

in **Bolnagri**  <kbd>`x`</kbd> is for half the word and in **KaGaPa** it's <kbd>`f`</kbd>

eg:

- Hindi ( Bolnagri )

  - <kbd>s+x+w+a+d</kbd> ==>  स्वाद
  - <kbd>`Right Alt  + a`</kbd> **+** <kbd>`Shift + o`</kbd> ==> अौ
- Hindi  ( KaGaPa Phonetic )

  - <kbd>s+f+v+a+d</kbd> ==> स्वाद
  - <kbd>`Right Alt + a`</kbd> +  <kbd>`Shift+v`</kbd>  ==> अौ

---

If you do not know which Hindi font currently loaded then check by pressing these keys

#### Hindi (Bolnagri)

<kbd>q</kbd> = nothing (white space)  ; <kbd>w</kbd> = व

#### Hindi (KaGaPa Phonetic)

<kbd>q</kbd> = ‌ट   ; <kbd>w</kbd> = ड

[Reference](http://www.indlinux.org/wiki/index.php/BolNagri)

Comment: short and smart answer... Left Alt key not supported right alt key is working . :)