# iBus m17n Hindi itrans keystrokes

Tags: 18.04

I am new to Ubuntu. Installed iBus m17n for Hindi typing in transliteration mode just as in Google Input Tools.
However I am not able to type some special characters like ड़, or how to put upper dot '˙' as in Honge or Hain in Hindi.
Can some body help me find out keystrokes for all Hindi characters for iBus transliteration mode.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to type half Hindi character with Hindi (Bolnagri) layout?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367761/how-to-type-half-hindi-character-with-hindi-bolnagri-layout)

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy to type a  `ं` in ibus-m17n. The only thing is I use itrans mode instead of transliteration. So if you are using itrans mode here is what you have to do.

After any consonant that you type, you need the vowel अं. To get it simply type a capital `M` after the consonant.

To type होंगे you have to type `hoMge`

To type हैं you have to type `haiM`

To type ॐ you have to type `AUM`